# Dynamic EventSource with flask and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am currently building a tool using flask that does various actions using ssh. One of those actions is using DD to copy from X to Y.

I currently have the following javascript set up on my page

```
    <script>
      var source == new EventSource("/dd");
      source.onmessage = function(event){
        $('.determinate'.css('width', event.data+'%')
        if(event.data == 100){
          source.close()
          }
        }
```

Which calls the following flask generator which parse's the stdout of DD to return a % value for the current progress.

```
@app.route('/dd')
def progress():
  def generate():
    ssh.SSHClient('127.0.0.1', username, password)
    chan =  ssh.get_transport().open_session()
    chan.settimeout(10800)
    try:
      ssh.do('dd if=/dev/sda of=/test.img')
      while data:
        data = chan.recv_stderr(1024)
          try:
            yield "data: " + str(data) + "\n\n\"

  return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

The above is pseudo code, but the things i want to be able to change are the DD command (dd if=/dev/sda of=/test/img) from variables i get from the form that triggers this page, as well as the hostname from the ssh.connect function with request.remote_addr.

When i try to replace '127.0.0.1' with request.remote_addr i get an out of context error.

Is there anyway to pass flask/jinja2 variables such as {{ image.path }} to my generator view?. The pseudo code i want would be this, where hostname, and dd is dynamic ( changes are in curly brackets )

```
@app.route('/dd')
def progress():
  def generate():
    ssh.SSHClient({{ request.remote_addr }}, username, password)
    chan =  ssh.get_transport().open_session()
    chan.settimeout(10800)
    try:
      ssh.do('dd if={{ device }} of={{ image.path }}')
      while data:
        data = chan.recv_stderr(1024)
          try:
            yield "data: " + str(data) + "\n\n\"

  return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out, didn't read the last paragraph of the docs.

If You want to keep the context of the previous request in the generator just change

```
return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

to

```
 return Response(stream_with_context(generatE()), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

For passing data i just used the "session" object to pass data and then remove it when im done using it.